# Kubernetes: container does not started even after redis initialContainer has been running

Tags: kubernetes, redis

Two containers, redis and busybox:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-mydb
    image: redis
```

The state of init-mydb is Running, state of myapp-container is Waiting:
[image: State is running state is Waiting]

What wrong is with the container redis(init-mydb)? It writes Running, so the depending container must start.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the initContainer must be in status Completed